Robot framework keyword hierarchy
Hi I have one problem with organizing robot keywords. I have some high level keywords which should be used directly in Test Cases and the I have lower level keywords which should not be used directly in Test Cases but only by some other specific keywords. I would need something similar to what is in Java with private and public methods. Is it good idea to use separate resource files for high level keywords and other resource files for lower level keywords?
Thank you.
